# How to make a file research specifying the final letters of the file

Tags: windows-10, file-extension, file-search

I need to find a file in a large folder using Microsoft Windows 10. The file is a Matlab script, that has extension ".m". I tried to search using "*.m", but the problem is that in such case the research proposes not only the script files (extension ".m") but also the figure files, also having extension that starts with ".m" (more precisely, ".mat"). This way, the amount of files I have to go through remains very (too) large.

My question is: is there a way to specify that the research must look for file having ".m" as END of the file name, and nothing more? I tried using the spacebar, but it does not help.

Comment: Are you wanting to search from explorer or from a cmd shell?

Comment: [How to search files in windows file explorer with specified extension name?](//stackoverflow.com/q/30364978)